# Differentiation with integration region depending on $x$ to solve for decreasing energy of wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I want to show that for the general wave equation $u_{tt} - \nabla \cdot (c^2\nabla u) + qu = 0, \quad u(x, 0) = \phi(x), \quad u_t(x, 0) = \phi(x)$
we have

$$ E(t) = \int_{|x-x_0| < R_0 - c_2t} (u_t^2 + c(x)^2|\nabla u|^2 + q(x)u^2) \, dx $$ is non-increasing when $c, q \geq 0$ and $c_1 \leq c(x) \leq c_2$ for some $c_1, c_2 > 0$.

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, I know by Leibniz's Theorem that $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(x, t) \, dx = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial t} \, dx + b'(t)f(b(t), t) - a'(t)f(a(t), t)$$ from which I am able to prove the desired result. Is there an analogous version of this theorem which lets me take a derivative of the integral where the limits of integration as defined as functions of $t$?

Comment: I realize that I can reduce it to the one-dimensional case by using a change-of-variables to polar coordinates where the ouster integral will be from $r = 0$ to $r = R_0 - c_2t$, but I'm wondering if it can be done without this.

Comment: This theorem enables one to take the derivative of an integral where the limits of integration are functions of t. Is the energy of the wave defined as you did or is the last term, $qu^2$, unnecessary? @ shuckles

Comment: Is there a higher dimension generalization of this theorem? I'm having trouble applying it. The energy I'm working with indeed includes the last $q(x)u^2$ term, as that will be necessary to later apply the divergence theorem and write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ in terms of the PDE for the wave equation.